# Does Custom PreferenceActivity Need To Define List

Tags: android, android-preferences

Does a custom PreferenceActivity need to define a List?

If I do not define a list as part of my content associated with my custom PreferenceActivity, I get the following RuntimeException:

> Your content must have a ListView
>   whose id attribute is
>   'android.R.id.list'

I am trying to create a custom PreferenceActivity that shows two lists:

1. One list that adds selections to the other list
2. One list that allows the user to move items up or down, or delete them (probably with a context menu)

What is a "preferred" way of doing this?

Thanks,
wTs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PreferenceActivity extends ListActivity, so I assume it needs a List.

When I don't understand things my preferred way is to Use the Source® : [PreferenceActivity](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.java)

**Edited:**

I'd take this approach:

1. Copy PreferenceActivity to a new class.
2. Create you own layout for your Activity (take a look at [ListActivity docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html)). Add a second ListView to it.
3. Make sure that all works as original PreferenceActivity.
4. Start adding code for the second ListView.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is u probably use settings loaded from an xml file and used

setContentView(layoutId);
...

**use: addPreferencesFromResource(layoutId);
instead.**

and you can skip the steps described by 'Peter Knego' and can directly use the Preferences without adding an listview.

Answer (score 0):

you can add preference to your *PreferenceScreen* use *for* statement to add it multiple times

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
     PreferenceScreen preference;
     preferenceScreen = getPreferenceScreen();
     PreferenceScreen new_preference = new Preference(this);
     new_preference.setKey("unique_key");
     new_preference.setTitle("new_title");
     preferenceSreen.addPreference(new_preference);
}
```